# No internet access through L2TP/Ipsec using Ubuntu 18.04 - Routing table

Tags: ubuntu, routing, l2tp

I have set up a VPN network using the package https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp.

The VPN works well (on certain situations) but I think there's a problem with the routing.

When I'm not connected to any VPN, the routing table looks like this:

[Routing table before connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLr6t.png)

As soon as I connect to the VPN, my internet connection drops and my VPN starts working.

[Routing table after connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN6xx.png)

If I use the option "Use this connection only for resources on its network" the opposite happens: I have internet connection but it's like I'm not connected to the VPN.

[Routing table after VPN using "local resources"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPamz.png)

Is there something I can do on my client-side?
By the way, using Windows to connect to this network doesn't make my internet connection to drop and everything works flawlessly.

**UPDATE**

Solved the issue! In fact, the whole problem was the routing table.
I had to add an entry considering my VPN subnet 172.30.0.0, mask 255.255.255.0 and gateway pointing to my VPN gateway.

For future generations, it's better using other VPN than L2TP/IPsec on Linux distributions. It was much easier to set this on Windows/Mac environment.

PS: of course, I don't have a good network background but this guide made me understanding some basic stuff.

Comment: thanks a lot. For me it was `sudo route add -net 10.1.0.0/24 ppp0`